# Change media player object witdh for different browsers

Tags: css, asp.net, browser, cross-browser

I have a media player object on asp.net web application. Chrome and firefox shows it as vlc player and IE shows it as microsoft windows media player.

this makes difference width of the embedded audio player object. I want to adjust different width of media player for different browser using css. What should I do for it?

Audio Player Code:

```
<div CssClass="media_player">
            <object name="MMPlayer1" id="MMPlayer1" classid="CLSID:22D6F312-B0F6-11D0-94AB-0080C74C7E95"
                height="68" width="680" standby="Loading Media Player components..." type="application/x-oleobject"
                codebase="http://activex.microsoft.com/activex/controls/mplayer/en/nsm p2inf.cab#Version=6,4,7,1112">
                <param name="fileName" value="ding.wav">
                <param name="autoStart" value="false">
                <param name="showControls" value="true">
                <param name="AllowChangeDisplaySize" value="false">
                <param name="ClickToPlay" value="true">
                <param name="ShowDisplay" value="0">
                <param name="ShowDisplay" value="false">
                <param name="ShowStatusBar" value="1" />
                <embed type="application/x-mplayer2" pluginspage="http://www.microsoft.com/Windows/MediaPlayer/"
                    src="http://localhost:50451/ding.wav" autostart="false" width="680" height="68">
                </embed>
            </object>
        </div>
```

css:

```
    .media_player
{
    margin-left:0;
    margin-top:0;
    width:680px;
    height:70px;
    background-color:White;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use different browser specific CSS selectors in your HTML header. Using [this site](http://browserhacks.com/), that would give you:

```
<style type="text/css">
    /* Default */
    .media_player {
        width:500px;
    }
    /* Firefox */
    body:last-child .media_player, x:-moz-any-link {
        width:600px;
    }
    /* Chrome (and Safari) */
    .media_player:not(*:root) {
        width:700px;
    }
</style>
<!--[if IE]><style type="text/css">
    /* Internet Explorer */
    .media_player {
        width:800px;
    }
</style><![endif]-->
```

However, you might want to make sure that you have all browsers included, and not only these three. To be sure of this, you might want to use a JavaScript plugin such as [this one](http://rafael.adm.br/css_browser_selector/).